# select option value click then automatically select another page select option which user select before using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, css

Hello Guys i have query. i want when user click on select option and when he click on option in another page show selected option automatically click which user click before with jquery.

This is my code please check.

FRONT PAGE SELECT OPTION WHERE USER CAN SELECT OPTION

```
    <form action="https://mycustompage.com">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-12 p-lg-0 p-md-0 m-lg-0 m-md-0 mb-0 mobilespace">
    <div class="select-1">
    <div data-select-box="">
                                                    <div class="custom_select _1" style="cursor: pointer;position: relative;"><div class="option_title" style="position: relative;">2<div class="arrow" style="position: absolute; right: 10px; top: 42%;"></div></div><div class="select_opts under" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; z-index: 1000; height: 354px; bottom: initial; max-height: none; display: none; overflow-x: auto;"><div class="option" data-option="1">College</div><div class="option" data-option="2">1</div><div class="option current" data-option="3">2</div><div class="option" data-option="4">3</div><div class="option" data-option="5">4</div><div class="option" data-option="6">5</div></div></div><select name="select-1" id="select-11" required="" class="customized" style="display: none;"><option value="" data-option="1">College</option><option value="" data-option="2">1</option><option value="" data-option="3" selected="selected">2</option><option value="" data-option="4">3</option><option value="" data-option="5">4</option><option value="" data-option="6">5</option></select>
                                                    </div>
    <p></p></div>
    <p></p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-12 p-lg-0 p-md-0 m-lg-0 m-md-0 mb-0 mobilespace">
    <div class="select-2">
    <div data-select-box="">
                                                    <div class="custom_select _2" style="cursor: pointer;position: relative;"><div class="option_title" style="position: relative;">4<div class="arrow" style="position: absolute; right: 10px; top: 42%;"></div></div><div class="select_opts under" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; z-index: 1000; height: 354px; bottom: initial; max-height: none; display: none; overflow-x: auto;"><div class="option" data-option="7">School</div><div class="option" data-option="8">1</div><div class="option" data-option="9">2</div><div class="option" data-option="10">3</div><div class="option current" data-option="11">4</div><div class="option" data-option="12">5</div></div></div><select name="select-2" id="select-22" class="customized" style="display: none;"><option value="" data-option="7">School</option><option value="" data-option="8">1</option><option value="" data-option="9">2</option><option value="" data-option="10">3</option><option value="" data-option="11" selected="selected">4</option><option value="" data-option="12">5</option></select>
                                                    </div>
    <p></p></div>
    <p></p></div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-12 p-lg-0 p-md-0 m-lg-0 m-md-0 mb-0 mobilespace">
    <div class="btn-book">
                                                    <a href="https://mycustompage.com" class="">BOOK NOW</a>
                                                </div>
    <p></p></div>
    <p></p></div>
    <p></p></form>
```

BOOKING FORM WHERE SELECTED OPTION AUTOMATICLY CLICK (https://mycustompage.com)

```
    <form action="THANKYOU">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-12 p-lg-0 p-md-0 m-lg-0 m-md-0 mb-0 mobilespace">
    <div class="select-1">
    <div data-select-box="">
                                                    <div class="custom_select _1" style="cursor: pointer;position: relative;"><div class="option_title" style="position: relative;">2<div class="arrow" style="position: absolute; right: 10px; top: 42%;"></div></div><div class="select_opts under" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; z-index: 1000; height: 354px; bottom: initial; max-height: none; display: none; overflow-x: auto;"><div class="option" data-option="1">College</div><div class="option" data-option="2">1</div><div class="option current" data-option="3">2</div><div class="option" data-option="4">3</div><div class="option" data-option="5">4</div><div class="option" data-option="6">5</div></div></div><select name="select-1" id="select-11" required="" class="customized" style="display: none;"><option value="" data-option="1">College</option><option value="" data-option="2">1</option><option value="" data-option="3" selected="selected">2</option><option value="" data-option="4">3</option><option value="" data-option="5">4</option><option value="" data-option="6">5</option></select>
                                                    </div>
    <p></p></div>
    <p></p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-12 p-lg-0 p-md-0 m-lg-0 m-md-0 mb-0 mobilespace">
    <div class="select-2">
    <div data-select-box="">
                                                    <div class="custom_select _2" style="cursor: pointer;position: relative;"><div class="option_title" style="position: relative;">4<div class="arrow" style="position: absolute; right: 10px; top: 42%;"></div></div><div class="select_opts under" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; z-index: 1000; height: 354px; bottom: initial; max-height: none; display: none; overflow-x: auto;"><div class="option" data-option="7">School</div><div class="option" data-option="8">1</div><div class="option" data-option="9">2</div><div class="option" data-option="10">3</div><div class="option current" data-option="11">4</div><div class="option" data-option="12">5</div></div></div><select name="select-2" id="select-22" class="customized" style="display: none;"><option value="" data-option="7">School</option><option value="" data-option="8">1</option><option value="" data-option="9">2</option><option value="" data-option="10">3</option><option value="" data-option="11" selected="selected">4</option><option value="" data-option="12">5</option></select>
                                                    </div>
    <p></p></div>
    <p></p></div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-12 p-lg-0 p-md-0 m-lg-0 m-md-0 mb-0 mobilespace">
    <div class="btn-book">
                                                    <a href="" class="">BOOK NOW</a>
                                                </div>
    <p></p></div>
    <p></p></div>
    <p></p></form>
```

Comment: Is this click based on DB? If not then you can use localstorage for this..

Comment: @PrashantPatil Thanks for your comment will you please tell me how to do this with jquery in answer thanks